# How can I get the text to wrap inside bootstrap col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <h1 class='headline'>Pardon Our Dust! We Are Building Something Great!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
</div>
```

Styled with bootstrap and the following CSS:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a {
font-family: 'Raleway', 'Droid Sans';
color: black;
line-height: 120%;
}
.headline {
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

When the screen width dips below 990px it should be printing on multiple lines but instead the scrollbar just pops up. I feel like it defeats the purpose of using fluid containers if the rows don't expand in height. Any recomendations on how to solve this?

Here is what i get: http://www.beehivefinancial.com/fap/

Comment: Seems to wrap nicely for me as it should. Could you provide a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @DarrenH Here is what I see http://ec2-34-228-162-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com/fap/index.php

Comment: I can not see any misbehaviour in the code you provided. Maybe the problem is in other parts of the code, isn't there other CSS that may interfere?

Comment: Link in the question is not reachable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess the problem is in the HTML, try applying the class `.col-md-offset-X` instead of emply columns, i.e.:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col.col-md-10 .col-md-offset-1">
        <h1 class="headline">Pardon Our Dust! We Are Building Something Great!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <h1 class="headline">Pardon Our Dust! We Are Building Something Great!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution I came up with. So I took a look at the bootstrap classes, and it looks like the width is set to `width:auto; max-width:none;`. So I took the best that `col-auto` had to offer, inserted my page max of `990px`, and created the following class in my own style sheet:

```
.auto-col {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding: 0px 15px;
-ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
flex: 0 0 auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 990px;
}
```

Its a bulky work-around, but it fixed my issue.